# How to create custom text-to-speech engine

Tags: android, text-to-speech

As I know, TTS needs TTS engine to speak one language. In Android emulator 2.2, Pico TTS engine is default. It has only some popular languages. I can see some engines on Market which must be purchased to install. My question: **is there any way to create a custom engine which support other languages?(by programming or using software)**

(I don't know if I should post this question in StackOverflow or SuperUser. If wrong place, please migrate it)

Comment: Please specify for which language you want to enable TTS functionality. Is your requirement for limited vocabulary (e.g TTS functionality for just digits 0 to 9) or for arbitrary text input ?

Comment: Any language if possible, I mean I want to create a new TTS engine by coding.

Answer (score 11):

I am also interested in making my tts engine. Here are some information I've found. On [this link](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/tts-for-android/EzXyyqG7cvw) you can find a brief description what you have to do to make your tts engine for android. Since API level 14 there is abstract class for tts engine implementation. More on [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeechService.html).

But making conversion from text to speech isn't so easy. Some basic information what tts engine should implement can be found on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_synthesis).

Answer (score 1):

As far as my research goes the best architecture for making a TTS engine currently is Tacotron 2[[Paper here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1712.05884.pdf)], a neural network architecture for
speech synthesis directly from text (can easily capture via [OCR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition)). It has achieved a [MOS(mean opinion score)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_opinion_score#:%7E:text=Mean%20opinion%20score%20(MOS)%20is,of%20a%20stimulus%20or%20system.&text=MOS%20is%20a%20commonly%20used,not%20restricted%20to%20those%20modalities.) of 4.53 comparable to a MOS of 4.58 for professionally recorded speech. The official implementation of Tacotron 2 is not public but there is a tensorflow implementation made using tensorflow 1.15.0 [here](https://github.com/Rayhane-mamah/Tacotron-2). There is also a pytorch implementation by nvidia [here](https://github.com/NVIDIA/tacotron2) which is more currently maintained. Both implementations can be retrained using dataset for a new language(language with no TTS implementation yet) for easy implementation of a TTS engine. You can also use the architectures above as a stepping stone to build your own architecture.

Answer (score 0):

Use mic recording software to record every sound in IPA or the Internation Phonetic Alphabet. Then create a JSON file that has a pronunciation value for every word key.
Finally, tell your program to speak each of the sounds in the IPA pronunciation to form an entire word. Depending on whether there is a question mark or a period, adjust the tone. If the sentence is happy sounding, increase the pitch. If the sentence is sad sounding decrease pitch.  Analyze the sentiments of the sentences to determine the pitch.