# How to create a TTS engine for Android 2.3?

Tags: android, text-to-speech

In Android 4.0, I can implement the `TextToSpeechService` class to create a TTS engine. There is even an example TTS engine in the SDK to follow, which is really easy.
However, I can't see any information on implementing a TTS engine on Android 2.3. What I want to achieve is like SVOX TTS engine.

Comment: Check this SO qusetion [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223680/how-to-create-custom-text-to-speech-engine/12495672#12495672)

Comment: @sinisha Thanks, the first link in the answer contains a [possible solution](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/tts-for-android/EzXyyqG7cvw/A5oLyQNeSYAJ), I will try it out to see if it works.

Comment: New welcome. But don't forget to vote up the answer if it's helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The link provided by sinisha leads to [a not very detailed solution](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/tts-for-android/EzXyyqG7cvw/A5oLyQNeSYAJ) by the author of a project called [eyes-free](http://code.google.com/p/eyes-free/). Then in the same project I found the author gave much [complete instructions](http://code.google.com/p/eyes-free/source/browse/trunk/documentation/TextToSpeech_Plugin_Engine_Examples/README.txt) on how to implement the TTS engine.

In summary, what we need to do is:

1. Implement the [TtsEngine interface](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/svox/+/master/pico/compat/include/TtsEngine.h) and compile it as libtts[NAME_OF_TTS_ENGINE_IN_LOWWER_CASE].so.
2. Create a dummy `Activity` class, named as [NAME_OF_TTS_ENGINE_IN_UPPER_CAMEL_CASE].
3. Bind the `android.intent.action.START_TTS_ENGINE` action intent to the  class.

The [Pico TTS Engine](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/svox/+/master/pico/) in the AOSP is an excellent example.